# Как получить / поймать событие в Android

Tags: android, kotlin, события, view, customview

Друзья, доброго времени суток. Есть небольшой вопрос к android комьюнити
Создал кастомную вьюшку и хочу определить для нее событие, а именно действие при нажатии на вью

В самой вью я переопределил метод onTouchEvent

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

   val flag = when (direction) {
        "left" -> isBelowTriangle(Point(event?.x,event?.y),
            Point(0f,height.toFloat()),
            Point(width.toFloat(),(height/ 1.3).toFloat()),
            Point(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat()))

        "right" -> isBelowTriangle(Point(event?.x,event?.y),
            Point(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat()),
            Point(0f,(height/ 1.3).toFloat()),
            Point(0f, height.toFloat()))

        else -> TODO()
    }

    return flag
}
```

Activity в которой используется данное view :

```
class RegistrationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var employerSide : View
lateinit var guestSide : View

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration)
    employerSide = findViewById(R.id.employerSide)
    guestSide = findViewById(R.id.guestSide)

}}
```

Не понимаю, как при нажатии на view поймать событие(объект MotionEvent?) и условно передать его в метод

Код layout(элементы перекрывают друг друга) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2">
    
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/left_registration"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/mercedes_office_employer_reg"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:paddingStart="70dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"

            >
        </ImageView>

        <custom_view.RegistrationCustomView
            android:id="@+id/employerSide"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:direction="left"
            app:color="@color/black_registration"
            app:line_color="@color/white_thighs_of_a_frightened_nymph"
            >
        </custom_view.RegistrationCustomView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/saimaaifasanslight"
            android:text="@string/employer"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:paddingTop="180dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white_thighs_of_a_frightened_nymph"
            >
        </TextView>
        
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/right_registration"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/dealership_mercedes_user_reg"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            >

        </ImageView>
        
        <custom_view.RegistrationCustomView
            android:id="@+id/guestSide"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:direction="right"
            app:color="@color/black_registration"
            app:line_color="@color/white_thighs_of_a_frightened_nymph"

            >
        </custom_view.RegistrationCustomView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/saimaaifasanslight"
            android:text="@string/guest"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:paddingTop="240dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_amber"
            />
        
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: проблема XY, лучше напишите в чём заключается задача, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: При нажатии на CustomView должна высчитываться точка нажатия(сделанно (в методе onTouchEvent) ), и в зависимости от ее координат должна вызываться либо одна активити, либо другая

Comment: Непонятно ничего. Событие `MotionEvent` у вас ловит сама вью и обрабатывать получается должна она же. Либо уберите `onTouchEvent()` из вью и назначьте ей `OnTouchListener` из активности. Либо определите колбек для событий (жестов, видимо), которые должна ловить вью, реализуйте его в активности, передайте во вью и вызывайте в кейсах `onTouchEvent()`

Comment: Ваша вью или не на экране, или не принимает тачи, или перекрыта чем-либо иным. Скорее второе, но возможно и третье.

Comment: т.е. если на экране у меня расположены 2 View, причем 2я View полностью перекрывает 1ю, то я не могу для 1ой определить событие касания?

Comment: Можете, но вы должны отключить отлов событий у верхней вью, только если она не обрабатывает никаких касаний, включая клики они передаются дальше по иерархии.

Comment: Все спасибо, разобрался что к чему, удалил метод onTouchEvent, событие обработал в activity, еще 1 вопрос, где лучше назначать обработчики событий(onCreate, OnStart, onResume)